# Passing values between activities in Android

Tags: android

I have a question about passing data between activities in Android. I tried to make an object Parcelable, it works but it's complicated to implement  for every class. I want to try to store the value as a global and fetch it in the other activity. I know that we should avoid globals, but at the moment I don't have any other solution. Any advice? Maybe if I used a collection, it should be Parcelable, right??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Give us some code examples to work from.  You can pass anything between activities with Intents.

Comment: Uhm seems to pass only Parcelable objects... But it's an hard work if object il composed by other objects... I have no code to show, but I wold simply define a class, instantiate a not parcelable object and pass the reference to another activity :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a strong feeling that we misunderstand the whole conception of `Activities`. Looking at the intent's `extra` mechanism of passing data I can say `Activity` was invented like something all-sufficient w/o need of exchanging large amount of data between each other. But I still havn't got a point of android core designers. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694301/good-alternatives-to-share-a-complex-tree-of-objects-between-activities-in-androi) thread, mb you'll find it helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences is a global store accessible to all activities

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

... but as a key/value store it is no more capable than intent extras.

Comment: Uhm, I would keep a global reference to the object, not store it in a file...I don't know that class, but it seems to be used to save preferences, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I have had success using a util class to hold `private static` objects that I need to pass around to other Activities within a single application.  Don't be afraid to try it.

Comment: You mean extends Application??

Comment: No need for that.  Just create a class that you can get/set your various objects to/from as needed.  Your Activities can then call `UtilClass.setCommonObject(Object o)` and `UtilClass.getCommonObject()` to pass the data around.

Comment: Yep, it's how I'm doing now :) It works but, yeah, I'm afraid to use that cause I think it's not a clean solution...